# Problema na configuração inicial do projecto da 2ª edição livro JavaEE com JSF Prime Faces e CDI

Tags: java-ee-7

Galera,

Comecei hoje a ler o livro que faço menção no titulo desta pergunta.

Seguindo passo a passo criei o servidor no eclipse, o projeto e o servlet inicial seguindo as instruções do livro. Mas seguindo o livro quando tento realizar o passo descrito nas paginas 33 e 34 que é de adicionar o projeto ao servidor, tenho a seguinte resposta: "There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server".

Eu sei outras formas de conseguir por isto a funcionar pois já criei vários projectos e adicionei no servidor sem problemas.

Coloco esta pergunta como uma forma de ajudar a melhorar o livro e ajudar ao novos nesta matéria.

Portanto gostaria de ter uma ajuda para fazer seguindo o livro, se calhar eu tenha falhado alguma coisa ou no livro esqueceu-se de mencionar algum passo.

As imagens do passo que pretendia executar.
Do Livro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha maquina (o erro):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2559/o-que-fazer-com-esta-pergunta

Comment: @JorgeB. Fui lá ver a discussão sobre a esta pergunta, se calhar o maior problema seja mesmo o titulo que parece um pouco genérico. Não sei se já teve a oportunidade de ver o livro que estou a ler, mas lá o autor pede que todas as duvidas sejam colocadas cá com a tag algaworks e como eu não tenho reputação suficiente para criar uma nova(algaworks não existe ainda) tag coloquei uma tag que fizesse um pouco de sentido por conta do conteúdo do livro. Mas aceito as criticas, são sempre bem vindas.

Comment: Ainda bem que esta *tag* não existe. Acho curioso ele pedir para criar uma *tag spam*. Alguma coisa me diz que você vai achar vários outros erros.

Comment: @Eudson que tal incluir o código/imagem do seu passo a passo descrito nas páginas 33 e 34?

Comment: E talvez uma resposta sua de como resolveu o problema, para que possamos ou não encontrar outras respostas. Assim como está a pergunta não dá para responder nada.

Comment: Ok @JorgeB. Farei isso. bigown não percebi: "_tag spam_".

Comment: @Eudson ele pediu para criar uma *tag* com nome da empresa dele. Isto é do interesse dele. As *tags* devem ser sobre conceitos, tecnologias, assuntos ou mesmo produtos **evidentes**, uma *tag* como nome de uma empresa de cursos não é adequada.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema que estava a ter e o livro não está errado, apenas não foram muito bem claros. Passo a explicar o problema e solução.

Problema:
No livro pedem que se crie um projecto maven simples e depois que se adicione ao projecto o *project* *facet* Dynamic Web Module versão 3.1. Fiz isso mas ao tentar adicionar o projecto ao serividor não funcionou, dando o erro que mostrei. Isto aconteceu porque tentei adicionar o projecto a um servidor tomcat7 e não tomcat8 como diz no livro. Mas só fiz isso porque não sabia que existia esse problema de compatibilidade entre a versão do facet com o servidor.

Solução:
Simples :-) ... Criei um servidor tomcat8 e funcionou.
Cheguei a essa conclusão graças a discussão abaixo no forum do eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/167292/

Acredito que devia se acrescentar no livro algo que fale sobre isso ou mesmo indicar um link que explique melhor, pois muitas vezes fazemos coisas sem saber porque.

Comment: Eudson, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Problemas de compatibilidade que ocorrem entre servidores de aplicação e APIs é algo bastante comum em Java. Infelizmente, não existe nada hoje que seja auto-evidente com relação a isto, então sempre que você for tentar colocar uma aplicação Java num servidor, você precisa verificar quais versões aquele servidor implementa dentre as APIs que sua aplicação usa. É importante considerar também qual a versão do Java o servidor suporta (por exemplo, o Tomcat 5 tinha alguns problemas com Java 6).

Comment: @utluiz Obrigado pela receção e pela dica, espero contribuir muito aqui e aprender também.

Comment: @Eudson - Já que gostaria de contribuir conosco(comunidade), fica uma sugestão: Leia o [tour]. Lá tem muita informação útil.

Comment: @emanuelsn Li, muito obrigado.